# Connecting one combo box to multiple pivot table/charts

Tags: excel

Hi after searching on youtube and google, i still dont understand how to connect one combo box to multiple pivot tables. For example, my combo box is a list with the different years "2012, 2013,2014" and i have pivot charts showing sales and profits by subcategories, sales of each customer segment and i want these pivot tables/charts to be able to be filtered by my combo box. essentially my combo box is my 'slicer'. so for example, if i pick 2012 using my combo box, then 2012 data for sales and profits by subcategories will show for the pivot chart. Im not sure where and how to start as im not familiar with VBA coding. thank you!

i was looking at this code but i dont think its works with form controls, it goes something like this "dim pivot_years_filters = pivot_table" i forgot the rest of the code cause it was taken from somewhere else

Comment: Why not use a slicer? That is what they are meant to do